# DUnit tests hierarchy

Tags: delphi, dunit

Currently I am using 2-level test hierarchy in DUnit (Test Project -> Test Case -> Test method; see example below). Is it possible to introduce 3rd level or even more levels?

[image: DUnit Example]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use test suites to create as many levels of nesting as you desire. The [documentation](http://dunit.sourceforge.net/README.html#_Building_test_suites) offers the following example:

> The `TestFramework` unit exposes the `TTestSuite` class, the class that
>   implements test suites, so you can create test hierarchies using more
>   explicit code:
>
> The following function, `UnitTests`, creates a test suite and adds the
>   two test classes to it:
>
> ```
> function UnitTests: ITestSuite; 
> var
>   ATestSuite: TTestSuite; 
> begin 
>   ATestSuite := TTestSuite.create('Some trivial tests'); 
>   ATestSuite.addTest(TTestArithmetic.Suite); 
>   ATestSuite.addTest(TTestStringlist.Suite);  
>   Result := ATestSuite; 
> end;
> ```
>
> Yet another way to implement the above function would be:
>
> ```
> function UnitTests: ITestSuite; 
> begin
>   Result := TTestSuite.Create(
>     'Some trivial tests',
>     [TTestArithmetic.Suite, TTestStringlist.Suite]
>   );
> end;
> ```
>
> In the above example, the `TTestSuite` constructor adds the tests in the passed array to the
>   suite.
>
> You can register a test suite created in any of the above ways by
>   using the same call you use to register individual test cases:
>
> ```
> initialization    
>   RegisterTest('Simple Test', UnitTests);
> end.
> ```
>
> When run with `GUITestRunner`, you will see the new hierarchy.

Comment: @Serg You can also add dots in the name under which you register the tests and DUnit will add a level per dot. For example, when you do `RegisterTest('Simple.Test', UnitTests);` It will create Simple as a node and Test as a subnode of that in the test hierarchy. Very nice feature to group tests in different units under the same functional name.

Comment: @Marjan +1 that's cool, didn't know that. I have a feeling that there's a lot of power in DUnit that is not widely know.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yep, found this little gem by accident as well :-)

Comment: Only sad thing about DUnit is that its "trunk" now only works with Delphi 2007 and newer - so for older releases of Delphi a separate (older) version is required.

Comment: @mjn: That was an unintentional break.  The admins are busy so getting it fixed is taking ages, but the intention is that it work back through Delphi 7.

Answer (score 11):

I build a hierarchy by putting backslashes in the `SuitePath'. For instance:

```
initialization

  RegisterTests('Group1\Group2', [TExampleTests1.Suite,
                                  TExampleTests2.Suite]);

  RegisterTests('Group1\Group3', [TExampleTests3.Suite,
                                  TExampleTests4.Suite]);
end.
```

In the end I get something like this:

[image: Example DUnit Test Hierarchy]

A lot less mucking around than with David's way, and you can spread your group definitions across disparate units.

Answer (score 3):

You can group related tests in test suites, which can be nested.

If you want to do it at run time, check out my "Open Component Test Framework (OpenCTF)" at [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/openctf/).