# DUnitX, how to use result of prior TestFixture in current TestFixture

Tags: delphi, dunitx, test-fixture

I have two TestFixures.
One creates Datas, the other works with some of them.

I have no good / elegant Idea how to transfer results from one Fixture to another.

Of course I can use a File, which is created in Create-Test and is read in Work-Test, but this is not realy great.

I tried TTestDataProvider, this looks good, besides, all Test Data (GetCaseParams) wwere created during Startup of the App.
The TestParams of Work-Test should be created after Create-Test runs.
I did not found a chance, that the Params were creates after the Create-Test.

Any Ideas, how to handle this?

Comment: Dependencies between different tests seem not to be a good idea in the first place. What if you decide to run the dependent test without the other?

Comment: Thank you Uwe.
Yes, we know this and keep it in mind..
Creating of the datas is very expensive, so we would prefere a possibility not to create them twice.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you are trying to implement some kind of tests hierarchy. If so then check [DUnit tests hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8878850/3636228).

Comment: But how to get the results from CreateDatas to WorkDatas?